# Es "... que sepa que he venido para avisarle" una oración completiva?

Tags: sintaxis, subordinadas

> ¿Acaso quiere delatarme? ¿**Que sepa** que he venido para avisarle?

¿Tengo razón si digo que la parte en negrita es una oracion completiva (*quiere que sepa que...*)?

Comment: Sí, yo diría que es completiva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo con lo que leo en [esta recopilación de oraciones completivas](http://hispanoteca.eu/Lexikon%20der%20Linguistik/o/ORACI%C3%93N%20COMPLETIVA.htm) y en [Subordinada sustantiva o completiva](http://habilis.udg.edu/myocid/oracion_sustantiva/), parece que sí es una oración completiva.

Básicamente, lo que debemos tener en cuenta es que:

> Las oraciones subordinadas sustantivas, también llamadas oraciones completivas, desempeñan en el interior de la oración principal funciones propias de los sintagmas nominales:
>
> -sujeto
>   -complemento directo
>   -término de una preposición:
>   complemento de régimen, complemento circunstancial, complemento de un sustantivo y complemento de un adjetivo.
>
> Para reconocer la función que desempeña en una oración compleja la oración subordinada sustantiva, se puede sustituir por un sustantivo o un sintagma nominal, por un pronombre demostrativo neutro o por el pronombre personal lo.

En este caso se trata de una oración subordinada sustantiva de complemento directo y puede sustituirse por un demostrativo o un pronombre átono:

> ¿Acaso **lo** quiere?
>
> ¿Acaso quiere **eso**?